# Why there are so many "ss" process on my server (CentOS with nginx serving the web)?

Tags: cpu-usage, high-load

There are about 500 concurrent users. It's because some famous people on social network repost a link.

This happened before. And our server were performing good.

But this time, the server is getting very slow and I noticed that the load is very high. In this picture the load is only 83.22 but that's because I rebooted it. Before rebooting it is 600+ (after editing this post, it's climbing to 200+, and it's still climbing, I guess it'd be above 600 soon)

I noticed that there're so many "ss" process. What are them? Any further advice on this case?

Thanks!

[image]

Update: after posting this question, it's getting higher:

[image]

Update:

I tried to find the source of this "ss" but it's like this:

[image]

Update: added another picture for `ps auxw`

Update:

Used `ps aux | grep ss` and listed this:

`/bin/sh -c ss -nlp | grep "[,=]27846," || netstat -nlp | grep "[[:space:]]27846/"`

[image]

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/ss - are you the one running `netstat` too?

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new to server tech. I Googled but only knew `ss` is something replacing `netstat`. I don't know whether I am running `netstat`.

Comment: @ceejayoz Please see my updated question, I saw some `netstat` in the updated `top` result.

Comment: Who set up this server?

Comment: check with "lsof" what those "ss" processes are doing and from where they are started. It looks to me like your server got hacked and someone started new processes by this name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <strike>`ps auxw` or</strike> `ps -ef` and look at parent process identifier (PPID) column.

Both `netstat` and its successor `ss` are mainly used for monitoring. These are normal admin tools, not any background services. The behavior you see is not normal. I think PPID will lead you to whatever process is spawning these. (Except for a PPID of 1, which usually means the parent had already died.)

Comment: I used the way to find but it's just saying it's `ss`. I've updated in the bottom of the original post. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Your website must have some sort of 'current viewers' / 'current connections' hook that is causing it to call out to ss or netstat to get the # of network connections. This is a very heavy thing to do on each page load.

Comment: What can I do for this case? Is this a normal thing when a lot of traffic rushes in?

Comment: No, most websites don't have a connection-counter like this, or they implement it in some other way. I suggest disabling whatever feature you have that is concerned with the # of connections as it is a significant performance issue.